# Having trouble understanding the definition of a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have some questions regarding the definition of a linked list as it was defined in my class.

This is what was used:

```
typedef struct node_t {
int x;
struct node_t *next;
} *Node;
```

Now, I understand that this way we created a shorter way to use pointers to the struct node_t. `Node` will be used as `struct node_t*`.

Now, say we want to create a linked list. For example:

```
Node node1 = malloc(sizeof(*node1));
Node node2 = malloc(sizeof(*node2));
Node node3 = malloc(sizeof(*node3));
node1->x = 1;
node1->next = node2;
node2->x = 4;
node2->next = node3;
node3->x = 9;
node3->next = NULL;
```

This is roughly how I imagine this (The circles represent the structures):

[image]
Now I know it's wrong, but I can't understand why. We have a pointer, `node1`, that points to our structure. Then, we point at `node2`, which points at another structure and so and so on.

Another things is, I can't understand how is it possible to have the longer arrows in the picture. Shouldn't we only be able to point to a structure from each lower part of the circle, and not to a pointer to a structure? How is this possible?

If anyone here could make things a little clearer it would be hugely appreciated. Thank a lot.

Comment: Having `Node` defined as a pointer-type is really going to cause confusion. In C the convention is to define plain types and have pointers be obvious, either as `Node*` (pointer) or through shorthand like `Node_ptr`. This is because [The Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three linked nodes, and additional local pointers pointing to them.
The nodes don't know anything about those local pointers though, even if it is often convenient to use their names to refer to the nodes.
Instead, they know the next node in the sequence, respectively the last node knows none.

Put another way, your image is flat-out wrong.

```
          +---+------+
node1 --> | 1 | next |
          +---+-|----+
                |
                v
          +---+------+
node2 --> | 4 | next |
          +---+-|----+
                |
                v
          +---+------+
node3 --> | 9 | NULL |
          +---+------+
```

Comment: This distinguishes between `node1` the variable which happens to be a pointer and the data it points to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have two questions. First of all, I simply can't understand why next won't point to the next pointer. If it was something like node1->next = *(node2); I would understand, but that's not the case. Second, if that's how it looks like, why do we need the pointers to each struct in the first place?

Comment: `node1->next = node2` copies *the value stored* in the object identified by `node2` into the object identified by `node1->next`.  This is analogous to how `int x = 1, y; y = x;` does not make `y` an alias for `x` -- they remain distinct variables, but they contain the same value.  In the pointer case, you end up with two pointer objects whose values both point to the same thing, not one that points to the other, or is somehow equivalent to the other.

Comment: I think I got it, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment is a transitive operation. So,

```
node1->next = node2;
```

would mean that `node1->next` points to whatever `node2` was pointing to. And, in particular, `node1->next` does not point to `node2` itself.

Each of `node1`, `node2`, and `node3` name a variable that is a pointer.

> ```
> node1       node2       node3
> +---+       +---+       +---+
> | * |       | * |       | * |
> + | +       + | +       + | +
>   v           v           v
> +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
> | 1 | * --> | 4 | * --> | 9 | * --> NULL
> +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
> ```

Comment: I can't understand why it is correct to use node1->next = node2; and not node1->next = *(node2);

Comment: `*node2` applies the dereference operator on the pointer. It is how you get to the value of the object rather than its address, which is what the pointer would contain.

Comment: Or from a different perspective, the type of `node1->next` is `struct node_t *`.  This is the same as the type of `node2`, but different from the type of `*node2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct node_t {
    int x;
    struct node_t *next;
} *Node;                   /* <-- don't typedef pointers */
```

Simply use `Node` instead of `Node *` and then allocate with:

```
Node *node1 = malloc(sizeof(*node1));
```

Why? Somebody looking at your code 100 lines below the declaration of your `typedef` will not inherently know whether `Node` is a type, or whether it is a *pointer-to-type*. This type of confusion will only grow as your code grows in size. Review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

(**note:** good job using the dereferenced pointer to set the typesize in `sizeof`)

**A Linked List**

A linked list is simply a clever data structure that allows you to iterate over a number of independently allocated nodes. Each node contains some `data` and then a pointer to the next node in the list, or `NULL` if that node is the final node in the list.

(for a doubly-linked list, you simply add a `prev` pointer that also points to the node before the current node in the list. You also have *circular* lists where the last node points back to the first allowing iteration from any node to any other node in the list regardless of which node you begin iterating with. For a doubly-linked circular list, you can iterate the entire list in both directions from any node)

In your case, your list is simply:

```
     node1    +-> node2    +-> node3
    +------+  |  +------+  |  +------+
    | data |  |  | data |  |  | data |
    |------|  |  |------|  |  |------|
    | next |--+  | next |--+  | next |---> NULL
    +------+     +------+     +------+
```

Where your `data` is a single integer value and your `next` pointer simply holds the address of the next node in your list, or `NULL` if it is the final node in the list. Adding your data, your list would be:

```
     node1    +-> node2    +-> node3
    +------+  |  +------+  |  +------+
    |   1  |  |  |   4  |  |  |   9  |
    |------|  |  |------|  |  |------|
    | next |--+  | next |--+  | next |---> NULL
    +------+     +------+     +------+
```

When creating a list, the first node is usually referred to as the **head** of the list and the last node the **tail** of the list. You must always preserve a pointer to the head of your list as that pointer holds the beginning list-address. For efficient insertions into the list, it is also a good idea to keep a pointer to the **tail** node so you can simply insert the new node without iterating over the list to find the last node each time, e.g.:

```
Node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));   /* allocate */
newnode->next = NULL;                       /* initialize next NULL */
tail->next = newnode;                       /* assign to tail */
tail = newnode;                             /* set new tail at newnode */
```

Lists are fundamental to C, there are many used in the Linux kernel itself. Take the time to understand them and how to write them in the differing variants. You'll be glad you did. Lastly, don't forget to write a simple function to free your list when you are done (and free the `data` as well if it is allocated). A simple free_list function would be:

```
void free_list (Node *list) 
{
    while (list) {
        Node *victim = list;    /* separate pointer to node to free    */
        list = list->next;      /* can you see why you iterate next... */
        free (victim);          /* before you free the victim node?    */
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.